# Trouble with problem involving finding a basis for the set

Tags: linear-algebra

Having a lot of trouble with these problems.Can someone show me how to show the set of vectors I have found spans $U$?

Problem Let $U=\{p \in \mathcal{P}_4(F):p(6)=0\}$.

(a).Find a basis of $U$.

Attempt:

(a). Using methods from this forum to help me I found a basis to be

$(x-6),(x^2-36),(x^3-216),(x^4-1296)$

The vectors are linearly independent since

$a(x-6)+b(x^2-36)+c(x^3-216)+d(x^4-1296)=0$

Thus $6a-36b-216c-1296d+ax+bx^2+cx^3+dx^4=0$

$\implies a=b=c=d=0$

Now I cannot figure out how to show that the set spans $U$ any help?

How am I supposed to know what a generic vector in $U$ is so I can write the generic vector as a linear combination of my basis?

Comment: $U$ is the set of fourth-degree polynomials that have $6$ as a root. Can you partially factor such a polynomial?

Comment: ok $(x-6)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ Is my basis still correct though?

Comment: Try to write this as a linear combination of your basis vectors. You should be able to factor $(x-6)$ out of both sides, reducing the problem to showing that the remaining factors form a basis of $\mathcal P_3$.

Comment: Can you not use the fact that each 'vector' is linearly independent and since each vector is not the zero vector, by definition the set spans $U$?

Comment: How did you come up with this basis in the first place? Depending on the method, that would’ve already shown that these vectors span the space.

Comment: The same way Anurag did

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e \in U$. Then $p(6)=0 \implies 1296a+216b+36c+6d+e=0$. Thus 
$e=-(1296a+216b+36c+6d)$. So
\begin{align*}
p(x) & =ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx-(1296a+216b+36c+6d)\\
&=a(x^4-1296)+b(x^3-216)+c(x^2-36)+d(x-6).
\end{align*}
Thus any $p(x) \in U$ is a linear combination of the vectors in your basis.

Comment: If you use this method to show the basis spans $U$ do you still have to show that the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: @68e1515 Technically yes, one should still show that the polynomials used are linearly independent. Howevere because of the distinct degrees of the polynomial it's fairly easy to deduce that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the method that you used to generate this basis, you should already know that these vectors span it. However, here are a couple of ways to verify this.

$U$ is the set of polynomials annihilated by the “evaluate at $6$” functional. By a variant of the Rank-Nullity theorem, this implies that $U$ is four-dimensional. All four polynomials in your basis clearly vanish at $x=6$ and they’re obviously linearly independent, so they must be a basis of $U$.

Alternatively, $U$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most four that have $6$ as a root. Every such polynomial is of the form $(x-6)(ax^3+bx^3+cx+d)$. Factoring $x-6$ out of your proposed basis vectors, the problem reduces to showing that $\{1,x+6,x^2+\cdots,x^3+\cdots\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal P_3(F)$, but these four polynomials are obviously linearly independent, so you’re done. Notice that I didn’t bother to work out all of the quotients of division by $x-6$. It’s enough to know that the four polynomials are all of different degree to determine that they’re independent.